# why does strcat not work inside function?

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, c-strings, function-definition, strcat

hi i'm trying to write a function that get 3 words, concatenate them to one word and print the word reverse.
i can't put the concatenated word into the ptr w1 in concatWords function.
another question - should i put '\0' in the end of every word?
can someone review my code?
thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 10

void initWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    printf("Enter first word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w1);
    printf("Enter second word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w2);
    printf("Enter third word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w3);
   
}
char* concatWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    int len = strlen(w1) + strlen(w2) + strlen(w3);
    w1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcat(w1, w2);
    strcat(w1, w3);
    return w1;
}

void printReversedWord(char *word) {
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (int i = len - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        printf("%c", word);
    } 
}

int main()
{
    char word1[N+1];
    char word2[N+1];
    char word3[N+1];
    char* longWord;
    initWords(word1, word2, word3);
    longWord = concatWords(word1, word2, word3);
    printReversedWord(longWord);
    free(longWord);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `strcat` wants a null-terminated string, switch from `malloc` to `calloc` to zero-fill the arrays or replace the first `strcat` with `strcpy` or null-terminate the array with `w1[0] = '\0';` between `malloc` and `strcat` calls.

Comment: memory allocation, like opening a file, can fail... Get in the habit of testing that malloc & friends have not returned a NULL pointer... When you write bigger programs, you'll be glad you have that good habit...

Comment: On why `strcat()` is best avoided: https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2001/12/11/back-to-basics/.  You took the trouble to determine the length of each string, use that information to `strcpy()` each string to the right place, because `strcat()` otherwise has to do the whole `strlen()` thing you already did, again.  `sizeof(char)` is always 1 by definition.  You need to include space for the nul terminator in your allocation (i.e. `len + 1`).

Answer (score 1):

```
char* concatWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    int len = strlen(w1) + strlen(w2) + strlen(w3);
    w1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcat(w1, w2);
    strcat(w1, w3);
    return w1;
}
```

This method:

- allocates memory that is not zeroed out, which will make it impossible to "cat" to it, because that assumes the string is null-terminated.
- allocates memory and then overwrites the pointer that points to the first word. That would be lost.
- allocates only memory for the three words, but misses the final zero that needs to be written to a null-terminated string
- does not communicate clearly, which parameters will or will not be changed be the function

So to fix this:

```
char* concatWords(const char* w1, const char* w2, const char* w3) {
    int len = strlen(w1) + strlen(w2) + strlen(w3);
    char* all = calloc(len + 1, sizeof(char));
    strcat(all, w1);
    strcat(all, w2);
    strcat(all, w3);
    return all;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You allocate memory that you assign to `w1`. Whatever `w1` was pointing at can therefore not be included in the final string. You need a separate variable for where to put the final result.

Example:

```c
char *concatWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    size_t w1len = strlen(w1);
    size_t w2len = strlen(w2);
    size_t w3len = strlen(w3);

    // the final result will be stored in memory pointed out by `res`:
    char *res = malloc(w1len + w2len + w3len + 1);  // +1 for null terminator
    if (res) {
        // copy the three strings where they belong:
        memcpy(res, w1, w1len);
        memcpy(res + w1len, w2, w2len);
        memcpy(res + w1len + w2len, w3, w3len + 1); // +1 for null terminator
    }
    return res;
}
```

Another issue: `printReversedWord` is missing the subscript operator on `word`:

```c
void printReversedWord(char *word) {
    for (size_t i = strlen(word); i-- > 0;) {
        printf("%c", word[i]);                // <- here
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/56f441noP)

Answer (score 1):

The function strcat deals with strings. That means that the both function arguments shall point to strings. And the function also builds a string.

Also as your function does not change passed strings then its parameters should have qualifier `const`. And the function shall build a new string. Otherwise after this statement

```
w1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
```

the first passed string is lost.

The function can look the following way

```
char * concatWords( const char *w1, const char *w2, const char *w3 ) 
{
    size_t len = strlen( w1 ) + strlen( w2 ) + strlen( w3 );
    char *result = malloc( len  + 1 );

    if ( result != NULL )
    {
        strcpy( result, w1 );
        strcat( result, w2 );
        strcat( result, w3 );
    }

    return result;
}
```

In turn the function `printReversedWord` can look the following way/ Pay attention to that your function implementation has a bug in this statement

```
printf("%c", word);
```

You have to write

```
printf("%c", word[i]);
```

Here is the updated function definition.

```
void printReversedWord( const char *word ) 
{
    size_t len = strlen( word );

    while ( len != 0 )
    {
        putchar( word[--len] );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

In main you should write

```
initWords( word1, word2, word3 );

longWord = concatWords(word1, word2, word3);

if ( longWord != NULL ) printReversedWord(longWord);

free( longWord );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* concatWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    int len = strlen(w1) + strlen(w2) + strlen(w3);
    w1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcat(w1, w2);
    strcat(w1, w3);
    return w1;
}
```

This function needs a fair bit of work. I'm assuming you want to allocate a new string sufficiently large for the job, concatenate `w1`, `w2` and `w3` into it, and return that new string.

Firstly, you overwrote the pointer for `w1` in this line:

```
w1 = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
```

So (in that function) you've now lost whatever was pointed to by `w1`, because `w1` is now pointed to newly-allocated memory.

Secondly, you've not allocated enough memory to store the string: you need an extra `+1` to include the terminal NUL character.

The original values of `w1`, `w2` and `w3` passed into the function were cast to `(char *)` from the base addresses of `char[]` arrays, so you can't use `w1 = realloc(w1, len+1);` - you'll need a new variable to store the new pointer.

Your `concatWords()` function should look like this:

```
char* concatWords(const char * const w1,
                  const char * const w2,
                  const char * const w3) {
    int len = strlen(w1) + strlen(w2) + strlen(w3) + 1; // Note the +1!
    new_w = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * len);
    strcpy(new_w, w1);
    strcat(new_w, w2);
    strcat(new_w, w3);
    return new_w;
}
```

Note that I've changed the function's parameter types, so that you don't accidentally change the values of the `w1`, `w2` or `w3` pointers, or the memory they point to. Always use minimum viable permissions, to prevent the risk of memory corruption. In C terms, *if you can `const` it, `const` it!*

Your `printReversedWord(char *word)` function won't work either. You're passing `word` to `printf()` as the argument to its `"%c"` format string, not the contents of the memory it's pointing to. You never use the index variable `i`!

This will have the effect of passing either the first or the last byte of the *pointer* value as the character to print, depending whether your CPU's big-endian or little-endian.

So if `word`'s value as a pointer was 0x12345678 (the location of the first character in the string it points to), you'd either be printing 0x12 (unprintable control character DC2) or 0x78 ('x') over and over again instead of the reversed contents of `word`. Of course, the actual effect would depend on the real pointer's value, not my example here.

It should be (something like):

```
void printReversedWord(const char * const word) {
    int len = strlen(word);
    for (int i = len - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        printf("%c", word[i]);
    }
    printf("\n"); // Don't forget the newline!
}
```

Note the `[i]` in the `printf()` argument. It indexes into the `char` array pointed to by `word`. Note also (again) the improvement in the parameter type. I've also added a newline at the end.

Finally, looking at:

```
#define N 10
void initWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    printf("Enter first word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w1);
    printf("Enter second word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w2);
    printf("Enter third word:\n");
    scanf("%10s", w3);
   
}
```

You've defined N, but then explicitly embedded `10` in the `scanf()` format strings. What happens if you change the value of N at a later point?

I'll leave the solution for that as an exercise for the student. :)

Answer (score 0):

The max length of each string is defined in a globally available token... Why not use it (and temporarily use a bit too much dynamic memory)?

```
char* concatWords(char *w1, char *w2, char *w3) {
    char *p = (char*)malloc( (3*N+1) * sizeof *p );
    if( p )
        sprintf( p, "%s%s%s", w1, w2, w3 );

    return p;
}
```

One could also add checking that all 3 incoming pointers are not NULL...